# How do I split a column in a data frame of 2 variables, depending on one variable, in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very long data frame (over 20 thousand observations) of two variables. Both numerical and including decimals.

```
Location Value
1        4.56
2        4.67
2        4.25 
5        4.89
5        5.67
5        6.68
...      ...
```

I need to split the data frame in vectors, by location. The result would be like:

```
loc1 = 4,56
loc2 = 4.67, 4.25
loc3 = 4.89, 5,67, 6,68
```

Only everything should be as automated as possible, since there are almost 1 thousand different locations.

I have tried using loops, the `split()` function, the `for` argument... But I need to be able to do it with a simple script, so the code goes through the first variable and creates different vectors with the values of the second one depending on the first.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `lst <- split(df1$Value, df1$Location); names(lst) <- paste0('loc', names(lst)); list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: You really want 1000 objects of similar structure cluttering your global environment?

Comment: It worked beautifully! A thousand thanks! Yeah, I should probably write it in a way where the lists are grouped as a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

From [akrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812099/how-do-i-split-a-column-in-a-data-frame-of-2-variables-depending-on-one-variabl#comment51549542_31812099):

```
lst <- split(df1$Value, df1$Location)
names(lst) <- paste0('loc', names(lst))
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```